# Warning memory received - Debug with Instruments

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory, instruments

I'm at the end of my first iOS app. Everything work fine but i've got some warning memory after a longtime use. I've used Instruments to check my memories allocation and it looks like i re-create object at every viewcontroller push. I don't really understand what i have to do to improve my memories allocation.

Here is what i get on Instruments :
[image: Instruments stack]

Here is a bunch of code which seems to be a problem :

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *startHomeViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"home-vc"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController: startHomeViewController animated:YES];
```

I think it's because i dont delete my object after use and when i re-push this view, it creates a new object.

My app has this storyboard :

```
Login -> push Tuto -> push Home -> push Enigma -> push LandingPage -> push DetailsPage -> popToRootViewController (login)
```

Have you an idea of what i should do ?

thx

Comment: you seem to to something in loading or appearing of your views that allocate smeary and never releases it... you should post that code instead of the above.

Comment: I allocate a lot of object in each vewdidLoad method, you think it's a bad idea ?

Comment: If you don't dealloc them at appropriate times, it is a bad thing. But no one can tell if you don't show what you are allocating-

Answer (score 0):

keep an instance of startHomeViewController and instantiate it only if it is nil. So, this is prevent the controller from getting created everytime.

`if(!self.homeViewController)
   {
      UIViewController *startHomeViewController = [storyboard  instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"home-vc"];
   }`